# Stacking dataframes from output of iterated function in R

Tags: r, loops, apply, tidyverse

I have written a function and am trying to iterate so that each value from a list becomes the input to the function once.

```
repeat100 <- function(B) {
  se100 <- replicate(100, bootandse(B))
  bandse <- data.frame("B" = B, "SE" = se100)
}
```

The output of this function is a dataframe with one column for the value of B that was inputted and another column for the SE. Like this, but with 100 rows.

```
B  SE
1  2
1  4
1  3
```

I have an object B with several values. I am trying to iterate repeat100() over each value of B.

```
B <- c(1, 4, 6, 20, 30)
```

How can I get the resulting output to be a dataframe that has the output of each repeat100() for each value of B stacked like this?

```
B  SE 
1  2
1  3
1  2 
4  5
4  3 
4  2
```

Comment: What is `bootandse`? Again as in an earlier post, pu some data to replicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lapply` with `rbind` to combine the data in one dataframe.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(B, repeat100))
```

Or `purrr::map_df` which is shorter.

```
purrr::map_df(B, repeat100)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(B, repeat100))
```